# how to print data from custom tableview using a button?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uibutton

I have a custom tableView that has 2 labels and a button. 
What i am trying to do is when i press the button in a particular cell the text from the labels in that cell is printed.

I have used delegate to make the button work like this.

```
**Protocol**

protocol YourCellDelegate : class {
    func didPressButton(_ tag: Int)
}

**UITableViewCell**

class YourCell : UITableViewCell
{
    weak var cellDelegate: YourCellDelegate?   

    // connect the button from your cell with this method
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        cellDelegate?.didPressButton(sender.tag)
    }         
    ...
}

**cellForRowAt Function**

cell.cellDelegate = self
cell.tag = indexPath.row

**final Function**

func didPressButton(_ tag: Int) {
     print("I have pressed a button")
}
```

Now how do i display data from that particular cell

Thanks a lot for your help

**Edit**

```
-getting contacts from phone-

    lazy var contacts: [CNContact] = {
        let contactStore = CNContactStore()
        let keysToFetch = [
            CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName),
            CNContactEmailAddressesKey,
            CNContactImageDataAvailableKey] as [Any]

        // Get all the containers
        var allContainers: [CNContainer] = []
        do {
            allContainers = try contactStore.containers(matching: nil)
        } catch {
            print("Error fetching containers")
        }

        var results: [CNContact] = []

        // Iterate all containers and append their contacts to our results array
        for container in allContainers {
            let fetchPredicate = CNContact.predicateForContactsInContainer(withIdentifier: container.identifier)

            do {
                let containerResults = try contactStore.unifiedContacts(matching: fetchPredicate, keysToFetch: keysToFetch as! [CNKeyDescriptor])
                results.append(contentsOf: containerResults)
            } catch {
                print("Error fetching results for container")
            }
        }

        return results
    }()

-cellForRowAt-

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PersonCell", for: indexPath) as? PersonCell

        let contacts = self.contacts[indexPath.row]
        cell?.updateUI(contact: contacts)

        cell?.cellDelegate = self as? YourCellDelegate
        cell?.tag = indexPath.row

        return cell!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whats the problem in displaying data here. You are sending the index value as tag in the `didPressButton` delegate as parameter. As you get the index values in the delegate here you just need to display the values inside it.

Assuming you are passing the value from an array in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you just need to print it as follows.

```
func didPressButton(_ tag: Int) {
     print("I have pressed a button")
     let contacts = self.contacts[tag]
     print(contacts.givenName)
}
```

Also, dont forget to set `YourCellDelegate` in the interface declaration of `UIViewController` like `class myViewController: UIViewController,YourCellDelegate {`

Comment: I am actually using the contacts framework to display phone contacts. now i just want to print name and email from the tableView

Comment: Could you please update the question with complete `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function. Want to know how you are passing the data.

Comment: Have you set the `YourCellDelegate` in the interface declaration of `UIViewController` like `class myViewController: UIViewController,YourCellDelegate  {`

Answer (score 1):

```
func didPressButton(_ tag: Int) {
     let selectedContact = self.contacts[tag]

    // Now use `selectedContact` to fetch Name and Phone Number 
}
```